# How to use case in laravel raw query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to select the row based on the current time in laravel. I have a query but it give a empty result.

```
$price_calc = DB::table('trip_price_fixing')
            ->select(DB::raw("DATE(D.datumTijd),
     CASE WHEN TIME(D.datumTijd) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '14:00:00' THEN 1
          WHEN TIME(D.datumTijd) BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '20:00:00' THEN 2
          WHEN TIME(D.datumTijd) BETWEEN '20:00:00' AND '24:00:00' THEN 3
     END "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate fields in select and name the secound aggregated field (in my example is `result`):

```
$price_calc = DB::table('trip_price_fixing')
        ->select(DB::raw("DATE(D.datumTijd) as date",
                 DB::raw("(CASE WHEN TIME(D.datumTijd) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '14:00:00' THEN 1
                          WHEN TIME(D.datumTijd) BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '20:00:00' THEN 2
                          WHEN TIME(D.datumTijd) BETWEEN '20:00:00' AND '24:00:00' THEN 3
 END) as result"))->get();
```

I also think that you have to drop the `D.` namespace from the query.

Comment: thanks filip.how to get the value of $price_calc using result??

Comment: I've update my answer. to get the results You have to itterate over `$price_calc` which is the collection of results records. When you get the single result you can access like: `$record->result`. You can read more on Laravel's docs.

Comment: i am try to iterate the result it give empty result?foreach($price_calc as $res)
  {
   echo $res;
  }

Comment: `$res` is a stdObject so you should do like: `{{ $res->result }}` according to the names of the fields from query.

Comment: could you: `dd($price_calc);` - that we can check whats inside

Comment: i did wrong db name.Now it alright.But it give Undefined property: stdClass::$result error message??

Comment: when i am did dd($price_calc) it give result of array:3 [
  0 => {#210
    +"DATE(start_time)": "0000-00-00"
  }
  1 => {#211
    +"DATE(start_time)": "0000-00-00"
  }
  2 => {#212
    +"DATE(start_time)": "0000-00-00"
  }
]

Comment: Look closely for my answer. You have to make alias for `DATE(D.datumTijd)`

Comment: $price_calc = DB::table('trip_price_fixing')
        ->select(DB::raw("DATE(D.start_time)",
                 DB::raw("(CASE WHEN TIME(D.start_time) BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '14:00:00' THEN 1
                          WHEN TIME(D.start_time) BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '20:00:00' THEN 2
                          WHEN TIME(D.start_time) BETWEEN '20:00:00' AND '24:00:00' THEN 3
 END) as result")))->get();